# ColorAccent code XML style

Tags: android, xml

I'm learning android in udacity, then i get stuck with this quiz question. Why my answer is wrong? Does anybody know what is the right answer for this question?

I've been googling for a long time, but still have not found the right answer.

Thanks for help anyway

[The quiz screenshot, click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guDUy.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You typed 536DPE, but they're asking for 536DFE

Comment: the right answer : <item name=colorAccent>#536DFE</item>. thanks.

sorrry i don't know how to close this question, but my problem already solved

Answer (score 0):

The color that you probably want is `#FD6FFF`.